# How mount through a command a remote directory at /Volumes but within a specific path and directory?

Tags: terminal, network, command-line, mount, folders

In Mac - *El Capitan* - through:

- `Finder` -> `Go` -> `Connect to Server`

Is possible do the connection with `smb://hostname/documents`

Therefore the `documents` remote directory is mounted on `/Volumes`

```
/Volumes
 documents
```

The problem is, what happen if other two machines have the same *documents* directory name? - Consider it how a mandatory policy of the company.

I want to know if is possible and how do the same approach done through `Finder` but with commands - it for *bash-shell* purposes - **but** letting define a specific path within `/Volumes`.

Therefore I want have in MacOS in `/Volumes` the following structure:

```
/Volumes
 192.168.1.55
    documents
 192.168.1.56
    documents
 192.168.1.57
    documents
```

It to have the isolated paths available to be used on some bash-shell scripts. How accomplish this goal?

Comment: Generally speaking this is possible if you use the command line. How do you authenticate yourself to mount these directories (do you need to add username/password)?

Comment: @nohillside through `Finder` is mandatory use username/password - Windows 10 was configured to asks for the credentials - it opens a small dialog window to write username/password. - Now I want take the command approach but with the option to define the location of the path/directory to be mounted